# How to get an independent copy of an XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to create a new XDocument as follows:

```
var xmlString = _documentDictionary[documentKey].ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

I now have `xml` which I would have though was a stand-alone instance of a document because I extracted the string from the original document and created a new one from that.

But when I modify `xml` and then inspect the `_documentDictionary[documentKey]` I can see that the original document has been modified also.

How can I get a new independent document from the existing collection that I have?

**Note:**

I've tried these but it doesn't work:

```
var xmlString = _documentDictionary[documentKey].ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
var copyDoc = new XDocument(xmlString);
```

and

```
var copyDoc = new XDocument(_documentDictionary[documentKey]);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is a [copy constructor defined for `XDocument` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341301.aspx):

```
var newDoc = new XDocument(xml);
```

> You use this constructor to make a deep copy of an XDocument.
>
> This constructor traverses all nodes and attributes in the document
>   specified in the other parameter, and creates copies of all nodes as
>   it assembles the newly initialized XDocument.

*Quick test*

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Test"));
var doc2 = new XDocument(doc);

doc.Root.Name = "Test2";

string name = doc.Root.Name.ToString();
string name2 = doc2.Root.Name.ToString();
```

`name` is `"Test2"` and `name2` is `"Test"`, what proofs that changes made on `doc` don't affect `doc2`.

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work. I'll give it another shot.

Comment: There is something weird going on. I just tried your test and it works, but when I try it on my own objects it is failing. I create the new document and modify it, changing the root name as you described and I can see that it's being updated in the original.

Comment: So you should check if you're creating a copy in good moment.

Comment: You have to make a copy before you do any changes to your source document.

Comment: It works now. I changed it so that I don't create the new document until the very last command before it needs it, and the issue is no longer there. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try to copy constructor, like;

```
var newDoc = new XDocument(xml);
```

From *[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341301.aspx)*:

> You use this constructor to make a deep **copy of an XDocument**.
>
> This constructor traverses all nodes and attributes in the document
>   specified in the other parameter, and creates copies of all nodes as
>   it assembles the newly initialized XDocument.