# How to retain the content format after transform in XML file

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I've XML file like this.

```
<Employees>
    <Employee

        Name="Name1"

        Address="Address">

        <Qualification Name="Degree"/> 

    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I'm modifying above XML file based on some business logic using `XLinq` `(var xd = XDocument.Load(filePath)`).

Finally i'm saving as `xd.Save(filePath)`. // **Problem**: Lost the original format.

```
<Employees>
    <Employee Name="Name1 Changed" Address="Address Changed">  
        <Qualification Name="Degree Changed"/> 
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

How can i retain original XML format.

Comment: This will., `var newXD=new XDocument(xd);`

Comment: How to save newXD again? I should again use newXD.Save(path)?

Comment: Take a look at this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782885/how-to-get-an-independent-copy-of-an-xdocument]

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your XDocument to an XmlDocument, you can use the PreserveWhitespace flag to make sure that the formatting doesn't change.

```
        XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
        myDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        myDoc.LoadXml(xd.ToString());
```

Then, use the save from the myDoc instead of the xd.

Comment: I cannot use XmlDocument in this context. Because i'm using LINQ to XML with Descendants.

Comment: Does that really matter?  From your post, it sounded like saving is the last thing that needed to be done.  the XmlDocument should retain the entire XDoc tree, descendants and all.  If you need to do no other manipulation, then this should work.  If you DO need more manipulation after the save, can you clarify that in your question?

Comment: I need to compare xml files before (Ex: 1 above) and after (Ex: 2 above) modifications. Because of the format i'm unable to find the difference easily.  for comparison i use winmerge.

Comment: Would it work to save an XmlDocument version of the XDoc before your manipulations, and then you'd have 2 XmlDocuments to compare?